# My Asp.Net 5 web api service recieves Posted Json as NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

Hello since I can't send Json data to Asp.Net 5's API Services I use this Method That I found in StackOverflow:

```
var param = function (obj) {
        var query = '';
        var name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;

        for (name in obj) {
            value = obj[name];

            if (value instanceof Array) {
                for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
                    subValue = value[i];
                    fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
                    innerObj = {};
                    innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                    query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                }
            }
            else if (value instanceof Object) {
                for (subName in value) {
                    subValue = value[subName];
                    fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
                    innerObj = {};
                    innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                    query += param(innerObj) + '&';
                }
            }
            else if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
                query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
            }
        }
        return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
    };
```

And I set:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

But when I progressed to more complex models, This param method can't convert a data model like:

```
{ RoleStatuses: [{Role: "Admin", IsInRole: true}, {Role: "User", IsInRole: false}, ...], UserName: "MyUser" }
```

And when I receive this model in API Service, UserName is recognized but Array count = 0, When I want to send this data as json both UserName and the Array are null, I stuck in this situation and cannot go further, so please help.

Comment: Firstly, if passing up Json to the api, the `Content-Type` header needs to be `application/json`. The best thing you could do to get some help would be to use Fiddler to grab the request (headers and POST Body) and also show the WebApi controller's method being called and we can see why the model binding isn't working for you.

Comment: How is your brilliant help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Internet I found My answer to place the attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateRoles")]
    public AdminAccountGenericResponse UpdateRoles([FromBody]RoleStatusUserModel model)
    {
```

**[FromBody]** in front of the Model parameter.

Comment: You should mark this as the "Accepted answer" even though you added it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

**POST is:**

JSON

RoleStatuses
    [Object { Role="Administrators",  IsUserInRole=false,  $$hashKey="object:53"}, Object { Role="Editors",  IsUserInRole=false,  $$hashKey="object:54"}, Object { Role="Members",  IsUserInRole=true,  $$hashKey="object:55"}, Object { Role="Users",  IsUserInRole=true,  $$hashKey="object:56"}]

0
    Object { Role="Administrators",  IsUserInRole=false,  $$hashKey="object:53"}

$$hashKey
    "object:53"

IsUserInRole
    false

Role
    "Administrators"

1
    Object { Role="Editors",  IsUserInRole=false,  $$hashKey="object:54"}

$$hashKey
    "object:54"

IsUserInRole
    false

Role
    "Editors"

2
    Object { Role="Members",  IsUserInRole=true,  $$hashKey="object:55"}

$$hashKey
    "object:55"

IsUserInRole
    true

Role
    "Members"

3
    Object { Role="Users",  IsUserInRole=true,  $$hashKey="object:56"}

$$hashKey
    "object:56"

IsUserInRole
    true

Role
    "Users"

UserName
    "Armin"

Source
{"RoleStatuses":[{"Role":"Administrators","IsUserInRole":false,"$$hashKey":"object:53"},{"Role":"Editors"
,"IsUserInRole":false,"$$hashKey":"object:54"},{"Role":"Members","IsUserInRole":true,"$$hashKey":"object
:55"},{"Role":"Users","IsUserInRole":true,"$$hashKey":"object:56"}],"UserName":"Armin"}

**And Headers Are:**

view source
Cache-Control
private, max-age=0
Content-Length
18964
Content-Type
text/html; charset=utf-8
Date
Sun, 08 Nov 2015 21:42:59 GMT
X-Powered-By
ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles
=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbWF6aWFfMDAwXERlc2t0b3BcV2ViQW5ndWxhclxzcmNcV2ViQW5ndWxhclx3d3dyb290XGFwaVxBZG1pbkFjY291bnRcVXBkYXRlUm9sZXM
=?=
view source
Accept
application/json
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control
no-cache
Connection
keep-alive
Content-Length
296
Content-Type
application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie
.ASPXANONYMOUS=BJm2d-pQ0QEkAAAANzQ1YWFkY2UtMTgyYi00NWE4LWI0ZTgtNjczZTcyZDY2Yzdi248xiSOVN90mD-0q5eEh6bMyxhZub9zJ7JIMsaU9BP81
; WebAngularCookie=C029A9A2E3E114C01C2D8F3829B00D7C18FDB1740D16E006EF09F098BA056355BC782EED8BBF129FF
8AB546EED2758409BEB5B0D4AF0D5EDDF11C6BF6FDB84235DCA60E86EBF1D4B1B34449915E4ACCF6A31F11DF0B83AC1FF0F3
A0A5FE17209C1BE91E7A90BE720FBD1B88AE46D6DFA4B0F450E29725F63B65974F5E552F15FBD37BF7C017E9A4DD13ECD942
09EE99672255DB2961B30FE319E608897CD513F81CA350C90374AF22000DAF39A69A5F7
Host
localhost:13661
Pragma
no-cache
Referer 
http://localhost:13661/Admin/ManageUser/?userName=Armin
RequestVerificationToken
CfDJ8LcZVsUv5KZJqpUyBqND_NYoqgSfNrV2Z1YEIuE6u2YSRdGF9Oec2SLkyfxmgIkOEBoQ9F2O7tm24jw-7_MXL-DGAbhQt-dcCYt0rY-hhBwHsA9w5Qf6ql4HegBAuHrkUCZbxgW8BTZkNlBuwlZOJ4c
:CfDJ8LcZVsUv5KZJqpUyBqND_NYE7Fd-vdtFHfxlHC2qLWHx2THGQuNbIhWLleaRBgC4SaQqkC1pEMP0yoi9p5QihhKxMpKe0da
M3OE5Wg6S8ZHyLG2dZyrUJYmGVB_izi_yq2hb4VgDngQlCzx6Qv7Fo28
User-Agent
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0

**Client Service:**

```
updateRoles: function (roleStatusUserModel, successSucceed, successFailed, error) {                
            $http({
                url: '/api/AdminAccount/UpdateRoles',
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(roleStatusUserModel),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'RequestVerificationToken': $rootScope.RequestVerificationToken
                }
            })
               .success(function (data) {
                   if (data.Success == true) {
                       theMessage = data.Message;
                       theError = data.Error;
                       successSucceed();
                   }
                   else {
                       theMessage = data.Message;
                       theError = data.Error;
                       successFailed();
                   }
               }).error(function () {
                   error();
               });
        }
```

**And Api service:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateRoles")]
    public AdminAccountGenericResponse UpdateRoles(RoleStatusUserModel model)
    {

        ValidateRequestHeader(Request);

        if (!Authorize(Context, Request, new string[] { "Administrators" }))
            throw new ApplicationException("Not Authorized");

        var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
        //MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            RoleStatus roleStat = model.RoleStatuses.FirstOrDefault(rs => rs.Role == role);

            if (roleStat != null)
            {
                if (roleStat.IsUserInRole == true && !Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, role))
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, role);
                }
                else if (roleStat.IsUserInRole == false && Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, role))
                {
                    Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(model.UserName, role);
                }
                else
                { }
            }
            else
            {
                return new AdminAccountGenericResponse
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "",
                    Error = "Role is null."
                };
            }
        }

        return new AdminAccountGenericResponse
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Roles Updated",
            Error = ""
        };
    }
```

**And the models:**

```
public class RoleStatus
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public bool IsUserInRole { get; set; }
}

public class RoleStatusUserModel
{
    public List<RoleStatus> RoleStatuses { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is ASP.NET 5, is it?

Comment: It is Asp.Net 5 service + Angularjs Client.